# Handle Pdf pages in website with Selenium via testng

Tags: web-applications, pdf, selenium, junit, testng

I am currently doing my automation on a website using selenium and Testng.All things were going fine . But when it came to check the data in some pdf reports i am facing problems.
I am not able to handle the pdf data as i am unable to assert any text present in the report.

So i need some guidelines if any other tool is useed with selenium to handle such pdf data on a website.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Selenium doesn't set any special limitations for library used for extracting text from pdf. Extraction itself you can do for example with:
PDFBox: [Download](http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html)  [examples](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html) or
iText: [Download](http://itextpdf.com/download.php) [examples](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=277)